# Javascript for nav highlight not working in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a great little script for highlighting links on a one page site that I found here on Stack Overflow. It works perfectly in Chrome and Edge but not in IE. Here is a snippet. Any suggestions?

```
    <head>
    <style>
        html, body, header, nav, main, section, p {
            display: block;
        }
        
        html, body {
            height: 100%; 
            margin: 0; 
            padding: 0; 
            width: 100%;
        }
        
        header {
            background-color: #000; 
            height: 50px; 
            left: 0; 
            margin: 0; 
            padding: 0; 
            position: fixed; 
            top: 0; 
            width: 100%;
        }
        
        nav {
            height: 50px; 
            margin: 0 auto;
            max-width: 600px;
            padding: 0;
            position: relative;
            top: 0;
        }
        
        nav a {
            color: #FFF;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 24px;
            height: 50px;
            line-height: 50px;
            margin-right: 24px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        
        nav a:hover {
            color: #666;
        }
        
        nav a.active {
            color: red;
        }
        
        main {
            margin: 0; padding: 0;
        }
        
        section {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            color: blue;
            height: 100vh; 
            margin: 0 auto;
            max-width: 600px;
            padding: 50px;
        }
        
        .one {
            background-color: #FFF;
        }
        
        .two {
            background-color: #999;
        }
        
        .three {
            background-color: #666;
        }
        
        .four {
            background-color: #333;
        }
        
        .five {
            background-color: #111;
        }
        
        h1 {
            font-size: 48px; line-height: 1; margin: 0; padding: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <a href="#one">One</a>
            <a href="#two">Two</a>
            <a href="#three">Three</a>
            <a href="#four">Four</a>
            <a href="#five">Five</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
        <section id="one" class="one">
            <h1>Section One</h1>
        </section>
        <section id="two" class="two">
            <h1>Section Two</h1>
        </section>
        <section id="three" class="three">
            <h1>Section Three</h1>
        </section>
        <section id="four" class="four">
            <h1>Section Four</h1>
        </section>
        <section id="five" class="five">
            <h1>Section Five</h1>
        </section>
    </main>
    
    <!--Navigation Highlight Script-->
    
    <script>
        const links = document.querySelectorAll('nav a');
        const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');

        function changeLinkState() {
          let index = sections.length;

          while(--index && window.scrollY + 1 < sections[index].offsetTop) {}

          links.forEach((link) => link.classList.remove('active'));
          links[index].classList.add('active');
        }

        changeLinkState();
        window.addEventListener('scroll', changeLinkState);
    </script>
</body>
```

Here is the full code. Of course I've omitted the html, title, and meta tags. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In what way exactly does it not work? Are errors reported? Does *anything* happen?

Comment: Hi Pointy. In IE nothing happens! All the links work fine. But they are not highlighted. They are supposed to be highlighted when their corresponding section reaches the top of the screen. This happens in Chrome and Edge. But not in IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are using an IE 11 browser.

The IE browser does not support the [Arrow functions(=>)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#browser_compatibility). It can be a possible reason that why your code is not working in the IE browser.

I have tried to modify your code, you can try to make a test with this code and let us know whether it works or not.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
    <title>demo</title>
    <style>
        html, body, header, nav, main, section, p {
            display: block;
        }
        
        html, body {
            height: 100%; 
            margin: 0; 
            padding: 0; 
            width: 100%;
        }
        
        header {
            background-color: #000; 
            height: 50px; 
            left: 0; 
            margin: 0; 
            padding: 0; 
            position: fixed; 
            top: 0; 
            width: 100%;
        }
        
        nav {
            height: 50px; 
            margin: 0 auto;
            max-width: 600px;
            padding: 0;
            position: relative;
            top: 0;
        }
        
        nav a {
            color: #FFF;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 24px;
            height: 50px;
            line-height: 50px;
            margin-right: 24px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        
        nav a:hover {
            color: #666;
        }
        
        nav a.active {
            color: red;
        }
        
        main {
            margin: 0; padding: 0;
        }
        
        section {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            color: blue;
            height: 100vh; 
            margin: 0 auto;
            max-width: 600px;
            padding: 50px;
        }
        
        .one {
            background-color: #FFF;
        }
        
        .two {
            background-color: #999;
        }
        
        .three {
            background-color: #666;
        }
        
        .four {
            background-color: #333;
        }
        
        .five {
            background-color: #111;
        }
        
        h1 {
            font-size: 48px; line-height: 1; margin: 0; padding: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <a href="#one" class="">One</a>
            <a href="#two" class="">Two</a>
            <a href="#three" class="">Three</a>
            <a href="#four" class="">Four</a>
            <a href="#five" class="">Five</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
        <section id="one" class="one">
            <h1>Section One</h1>
        </section>
        <section id="two" class="two">
            <h1>Section Two</h1>
        </section>
        <section id="three" class="three">
            <h1>Section Three</h1>
        </section>
        <section id="four" class="four">
            <h1>Section Four</h1>
        </section>
        <section id="five" class="five">
            <h1>Section Five</h1>
        </section>
    </main>
    
    <!--Navigation Highlight Script-->
    
    <script>
    
        const links = document.querySelectorAll('nav a');
        const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
        var reg = new RegExp('(^| )active($| )','g');

        function changeLinkState() 
    {
            let index = sections.length;
        var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop; 
        while(--index && scrollTop  + 1 < sections[index].offsetTop) 
        {
                
        }
            
        for (var i=0; i<links.length; i++) 
        {
                links[i].className = links[i].className.replace(reg,' ');
            }
        
        for (var i=0; i<links.length; i++) 
        {   
            if (sections[index].getAttribute("id")==links[i].getAttribute("href").substring(1)) 
            {           
                    links[i].className = "active";
            }
                
        }
    }
        changeLinkState();
        window.addEventListener('scroll', changeLinkState);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi Deepak. I tried your code. It works in Chrome and Edge. But it still doesn't work in IE. In IE it just highlights the last link the entire time. Thanks for your efforts. I appreciate it.

Comment: I suggest you please try to post the proper example that includes HTML, CSS, and JS. so that we can try to make a test and see the results.

Comment: Good idea Deepak. I'll just include the relevant HTML, CSS and JS.

Comment: Hi again Deepak. This is my first time using Stack Overflow. How do I post my full code? Should I submit it as a new question or replace the original code I submitted? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: No need to post a new question. You can edit the original post and try to include the code via code snippet. There are sections for HTML, CSS and JS. You can place the code there.

Comment: Hi Deepak. I tried editing my answer. But I receive an error message saying that my post is mainly code and that I need to include more details. I then tried elaborating on my question but received the same error.

Comment: @Elio, sorry for the late response. Your sample code requires many changes to make it compatible with the IE 11 browser. Please refer to my updated answer. I have also posted the test result. You can notice that it is working fine in the IE 11 browser. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Hi Deepak. Hooray! Your (many) changes allow the script to work perfectly in IE while continuing to work flawlessly in Chrome and Edge. Thank you so much for your help buddy. You are an absolute life saver! Best - Elio